# FFmpeg php set image size thumbnail

Tags: php, ffmpeg

```
$movie=new ffmpeg_movie(''.$url.'');
$duration = $movie->getDuration();
$uzanti = substr($url , -3);
$duration = date('i:s',''.$duration.'');
$framesay = $movie->getFrameCount();
$framerate = $movie->getFrameRate();
$framehesap = $thumb * $framerate;
$md5 = md5($url);
$frame = $movie->getFrame($framehesap);
$gd = $frame->toGDImage();
imagepng($gd,'../thumb/'.$md5.'.png');
```

I want to set image size. I'm using ffmpeg as you see. how can I set thumbnail size? (I want 220x130)

Answer (score 0):

Use `imagescale`:

```
$gd = imagescale($gd, 220, 130);
```

See here for all info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php

Edit: fixed it

Comment: Sorry; it returns the scaled image

Comment: See my edited answer, `imagescale()` returns the scaled image so you have to assign it to $gd. I was in a hurry :)